# No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute in angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel

HTML code

```
<li class="dropdownfilter" *ngIf="this.arr.inclues('Male')" (click)="getValueGender('Male',1,)" [(ngModel)]="M"><a>Male</a></li>
```

I'm facing the below exception

```
ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute
```

So I have added

```
<li class="dropdownfilter" name="gendermale" *ngIf="this.arr.inclues('Male')" (click)="getValueGender('Male',1,)" [(ngModel)]="M"><a>Male</a></li>
```

Now facing the below exception

```
ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'gendermale'
```

I'm facing this exception in many places of my code.

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8 contact">
    <input  id="passphn{{bus.busServiceId}}" (keyup)="onKeyPress($event)" class="form-control contact-number" type="text" [(ngModel)]="contactNumber" name="contact-number" placeholder="Phone" required pattern="(?<!\d)\d{10}(?!\d)" minlength="10" maxlength="10" />
    <div class="shake-tooltip-web-mobile" *ngIf="webMobileError != ''">{{webMobileError}}</div> <!-- Facing the same exception here -->
</div>

<div class="panel-body" *ngIf="dropingView == 'show'"> <!-- Here too -->
```

Comment: I don't think you can use the `[(ngModel)]` directive, as it's not a form element

Comment: (ngModel) [(ngModel)] [ngModel] which one can I use? Where can I use? pls let me know

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I have ngModel to my input tags. Some are insside <form> and some are not

Comment: But these are not `input` tags, they're `li` tags, which is why it wont work. You can't bind to the value attribute (which is what `ngModel` does) because `li`s don't have a value

Comment: Please see the edited question I'm facing the same even for div tags

Comment: @Krishna Can you create a simple StackBlitz that reproduces the problem please? There shouldn't be any issues with the bits you just added

Comment: Is there any possibility of facing that error there due the code above those?

Comment: If you have the `ngModel` directive on anything that is not a form control, then that could cause that error. It must only be on something like `input`, or `select`

Comment: Thankyou so much. I removed ngModel to button, list tags. No exceptions now

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't access with this.x in html.

```
<li class="dropdownfilter" *ngIf="arr.inclues('Male')" (click)="getValueGender('Male',1)"><a>Male</a></li>
```

Secondly, li tag doesnt have name attribute nor supports [(ngModel)] because it requires value property. ngModel is an angular build in directive. Two-way binding uses the syntax as [()], Property binding uses the syntax [] and Event binding uses the syntax as parenthesis ().